# Get View.OnClickListener from other class?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

i'm pretty new in Android and i'm stuck with handling `OnClickListeners`  from separate class

In my Main `Main_Activity` i have a lot of buttons and `View.OnClickListeners` to handle them . `OnClickListeners` looks messy in code, so i decided to move them in separate class where they will be helded.
And right after that I stuck with problem that  `Main_Activity` doesn’t want to apply them  from separated class .

I've tried to create method in `ListenersHolder` class ,that set designated listener that but this don't work because non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context:

```
 //code for separate class that helds listeners 
public  abstract class Listeners_Utils extends Main_Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private final View.OnClickListener listener;
private final Main_Activity main;

public Listeners_Utils (Main_Activity main, View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
    this.main = main;
}

 //listners itself
View.OnClickListener button1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view ) {
   /some code    }
};

View.OnClickListener button2Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view ) {
   /some code    }
};
.... 
View.OnClickListener buttonNListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view ) {
   /some code    }
};
```

method to get listener depends on that String will be printed

```
public View.OnClickListener getListener(String listenerName) {
    switch (listenerName) {
        case "button1":
            massButton.setOnClickListener(massListener);
            break;
        case "button2":
            lengthButton.setOnClickListener(lengthListener);
            break;
 return listener;
```

In my activity i have something like this, but it doesn't work

```
Button1.setOnClickListener(Listeners_Utils.getListener(button1);
Button2.setOnClickListener(Listeners_Utils.getListener(button2);
 ....
ButtonN.setOnClickListener(Listeners_Utils.getListener(buttonN);
```

So question is:
What is proper way to get listeners from `Listeners_Utils.class` in `Main_Activity.class` and apply them for specified button?

Thanks for considering my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's simpler for the activity to be handling its views on its own, but assuming you want to go your way something like this can work:

```
// Should not extend MainActivity 
public  class ListenersUtils {

    public static View.OnClickListener getListener(final MainActivity main, String listenerName) {
        switch (listenerName) {
            case "button1":
                return new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view ) {
                        //some code that can reference MainActivity
                    }
                };
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in your MainActivity:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(ListenersUtils.getListener("button1");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use Android Data Binding where you would be able to separate your logic from view. This way, all your listeners will be handled in a different class separate from and Activity or Fragment class. Below is a link to the official documentation by Google on data binding
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#event_handling

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: gotcha. i only provided a link because it was a whole lot of explanation to do from enabling data binding in app gradle to converting the layouts to a binding format and then implementing the listeners

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your goal is to make the abstract class for onClicklistener. But to answer how to get specific buttons in an activity, you can do it like this.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btn1;
    private Button btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.my_button2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.my_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.my_button2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ok2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions are good too, but if you want to stay in the same activity , you could also use this method 
If you don't want to create

```
button1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view ) {
 /some code    
     }
 };
```

You could use the attribute onClick in the XML file for the button.

For example : 
IN XML FILE

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Click me "
    android:onClick="createToast"
    />
```

In MainActivity : 
define the functionality you want to be performed when the button is clicked

```
 public void createToast(View view) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Clicked on the button " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ; 
}
```